# Making slides.js Compatible with JQuery 1.3.2

Tags: jquery, drupal, slider, version, jquery-1.3.2

My favorite slider plugin is compatible with JQuery versions 1.4.4+, but I can only use 1.3.2.

[slides.js](http://slidesjs.com/)

I see that it uses the **easing** option in its **fadeIn()** and **fadeOut()** calls, which I know is not supported in 1.3.2, so I tried stripping out those parts but still no luck.

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/AsXpR/

Any way to make it compatible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry to answer my own question, but I had actually missed an **easing** option when I was removing them. Once I removed it, the slider started working!

Here is a fiddle with the working javascript: http://jsfiddle.net/3dUXN/